# Get reference to MainWindow in custom main() in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, program-entry-point

I am trying to write a custom `Main()` function for my WPF app so I can parse the command line and configure the GUI based on the command line. I can't figure out how to get a reference to the `MainWindow` instance created by the default implementation of `Main()`. The auto-generated implementation found in `App.g.cs` is below:

```
public void InitializeComponent() {
    if (_contentLoaded) {
        return;
    }
    _contentLoaded = true;

    #line 5 "..\..\..\App.xaml"
    this.StartupUri = new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

    #line default
    #line hidden
    System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/MyApplication;component/app.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

    #line 1 "..\..\..\App.xaml"
    System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

    #line default
    #line hidden
}

[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
public static void Main() {
    MyApplication.App app = new MyApplication.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

The problem I'm running into is  trying to get a reference to my `MainWindow` class after it is instantiated (however that is actually done via `StartupUri`). I'd expect to be able to do something like:

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
public static void Main() {
    MyApplication.App app = new MyApplication.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    MyApplication.MainWindow w = (MyApplication.MainWindow)app.MainWindow;
    w.MyProgramIsAwesomeProperty = true;
    app.Run();
}
```

But, the `app.MainWindow` is always `null`. I've also tried the following and setting breakpoints on the `Console.WriteLine` lines, but the program never reaches those callbacks:

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
public static void Main() {
    MyApplication.App app = new MyApplication.App();
    app.LoadCompleted += app_LoadCompleted;
    app.Activated += app_Activated;
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}

static void app_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Activated");
}

static void app_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("LoadCompleted");
}
```

So, how can I get a reference to `MyApplication.MainWindow` after it's been instantiated in my `Main` function?

Comment: Try Application.Current.MainWindow

Comment: That is `null` as well. :-(

Comment: I think that's because you need to create an instance of MainWindow and then assign it to Application.Current.MainWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send something from the command line to the GUI, you're better off calling a method in your Application class and opening your GUI from that.

Open your App.xaml file, remove the `StartupUri` attribute from the `Application` element, and add a `Startup` attribute:

```
Startup="Application_Startup"
```

Then create an `Application_Startup` method in your `Application` class that reads the command line or whatever and sends that to your GUI:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Args contains command-line arguments.
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow(Whatever(e.Args));
    mw.Show();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use this vs overriding `OnStartup( StartupEventArgs e )` ?

Comment: So, is this answer basically doing what the `StartupUri` stuff does?

Comment: @clcto I remember a situation long ago where `OnStartup` wasn't called, but can't remember what the cause was. Yes, this basically does what `StartupUri` does, but does it before the main window is created, so you can do things like change the GUI, or even decide to not show the GUI, before it gets opened.

Comment: I just tried overriding `OnStartup` and it worked fine, but I will leave this answer as an alternate method.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, setting of `StartupUri` doesn't instantiate main window and doesn't set corresponding `Application.MainWindow` property. This happens later, after the call of `Run` method, that's why you're getting `null`.

The proper way is to avoid `StartupUri` and to override [`OnStartup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method (while you can add event handler, as proposed, it doesn't make much sense in derived class). Then, in `OnStartup`, you may instantiate main window directly and set the property you want to set.